# nginx duplicates host till 414 request too large

Tags: nginx

I try to make config to run with ip and port only.
somehow nginx repeats host and I can't understand why.
Example:
I go to addres

```
111.22.33.44:8010
```

and nginx redirects to address

```
http://111.22.33.44:8010/111.22.33.44/111.22.33.44/111.22.33.44/...
```

my config file:

```
#upstream 111.22.33.44 {
#    server localhost:8010 fail_timeout=0;
#}
#server {
#        listen 8010;
#        server_name 111.22.33.44;
#        return 301 http://111.22.33.44$request_uri;
#}
server {
        listen 8010;
        listen [::]:8010 default_server;
        server_name 111.22.33.44;

#        server_name 111.22.33.44;
        location /static/ {
                root /opt/;
        }
        location / {
                return 200 'gangnam style!';
#                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#                proxy_redirect off;
#                proxy_pass http://111.22.33.44;
        }
}
```